# Binary relations, closures and equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be the relation on $Z$ such that $xRy \iff x-y=c$.

Well, what I have so far is $R=\{ 0,-1,1,0,-1,1,0 \cdots\}$

1. Is $R^* $ and equivalence relation? Why not?

This is where problems start: I don't know what the definition of $R^* $. In fact, I cannot seem to find anything related to this in my notes. First off, is my relation $R$ correct at this point?

Comment: Unless $\;c=0\; $ the relation has no chance whatsoever to be reflexive and, thus, not an equivalence relation...But then you see what you get if $\;c=0\;$ , right? :)

Comment: @Dimitri : your question has several issues.  You never defined what $R^*$ is (an apparent typo).  Your "$R$" (which maybe was supposed to be $R^*$"?) should be a set of ordered pairs, and it isn't.

Comment: @DonAntonio: The question was not whether $R$ is an equivalence relation, but whether $R^*$ is -- I suppose this notation means the reflexive transitive closure of $R$.

Comment: Well, I see now...I've no idea what $\;R^*\;$ can be.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have never seen this notation before and it has been causing me some problems.

Comment: $R^*$ for reflexive transitive closure is commonly encountered _at least_ in connection with rewrite systems (such as the $\lambda$-calculus). Since this is tagged "discrete math" which is usually a support course for computer science, I think it is likely that this is the relevant meaning here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see now. And you're right, it is a Computer Science course. So this is just plain notation for a transitive closure?

Comment: If $\;R^*\;$ is *only* the reflexive/transitive closure then we still have issues here with symmetry, don't we?

Comment: Dimitri: Transitive _and reflexive_ closure, I would assume. The pure transitive closure would usually be $R^+$ (by analogy with regular expressions, for example). @DonAntonio: Yes, there are still symmetry issues.

Comment: In fact, when $c=1$ the resulting $R^*$ is a well-known relation on $\mathbb Z$...

Comment: With $\;c=0\;$ we get an even more well-known relation, me thinks...and way more boring, too.

Comment: If $R \subseteq  \Bbb Z X \Bbb Z$, then the only time $c=1$ is when $x>y$, no ?

Comment: @Dimitri: Right. Or when $x=y$, since the star (called the Kleene star) is the _reflexive_ transitive closure.

Comment: @HenningMakholm So, how do I formally define what $R^*$ is?

Comment: @Dimitri: One possibility would be "the intersection of all relations that contain $R$ and are reflexive and transitive".

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578754/relation-squared-of-xry-iff-x-y-c/586076#586076) about the same relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relation is not correct. A relation is defined to be a set of ordered pairs where the ordered pair (x,y) is included if xRy.